# Need help on best practice or better way of coding

Tags: apex

The Scenario here is there is Transaction(custom) object,each transaction is associated with a member and Loyalty product(Custom objects). There is a custom list button called process transactions which adds or redeems the points depending on the transaction type to the member.

The code below is working fine:

```
 global class ProcessTransaction{   

 WebService static void process(id[] transactionids){

  List<Member__c> MembersToUpdate =new List<Member__c>();
  List<Transaction__c> TransactionsToUpdate =new List<Transaction__c>();

   List<Transaction__c> listofTransactions =[SELECT Member__c,
                                                  Processing_Comment__c,
                                                  Product__c,
                                                  Status__c,
                                                  Sub_Type__c,
                                                  Transaction_Date__c,
                                                  Type__c FROM Transaction__c WHERE id IN :transactionids ];

         for(Transaction__c t:listofTransactions){
         Member__c Member =[SELECT Active__c,
                                                  Contact__c,
                                                  Enrolled_Date__c,
                                                  Expiration_Date__c,
                                                  Points__c,
                                                  Program_Enrolled__c,
                                                  Tier__c FROM Member__c WHERE id =:t.Member__c ][0];


         LoyaltyProduct__c product =[SELECT Product_points__c
                                                        FROM LoyaltyProduct__c WHERE id =:t.Product__c ][0];



         if(t.Type__c =='Accrual' && t.Sub_Type__c =='Product'){ 

         Member.Points__c = Member.Points__c+product.Product_points__c;
         t.Status__c ='Processed';
         t.Processing_Comment__c ='Points added to member';
         }
         else if(Member.Points__c > product.Product_points__c ) {
          Member.Points__c = Member.Points__c - product.Product_points__c;
         t.Status__c ='Processed';
         t.Processing_Comment__c ='Points redemed from member';

         }
         else if(Member.Points__c < product.Product_points__c ) {

         t.Status__c ='failed';
         t.Processing_Comment__c ='Not enough points to redem';

         }
         //MembersToUpdate.add(Member);
         //TransactionsToUpdate.add(t);

         update Member;
         update t;
         }

        //update MembersToUpdate;
        //update TransactionsToUpdate;
 }
}
```

> > Actual problem here is there is a possibility that when N number of transactions are selected X number of transactions can be associated
> >     with the same member,in that case i am getting the error while
> >     updating the list of members.(ERROR:Duplicate id's)
>
> So i changed the code to update a member at a time,i know this is not
>   a good way especially on a list button.

**Looking for suggestions on the better approach i should be following**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a SOQL query inside a loop will give you "Too many SOQL ..." exception and this line should be taken out and should be a map.

```
LoyaltyProduct__c product =[SELECT Product_points__c
                                                        FROM LoyaltyProduct__c WHERE id =:t.Product__c ][0];
```

For that, you need to collect all the Products in a list such as

```
List<Id> prodIds
```

and use it in the above query usign in operator

```
LoyaltyProduct__c product =[SELECT Product_points__c
                                                        FROM LoyaltyProduct__c WHERE id in : prodIds;
```

Again, to avoid duplicate Ids, you should use map to store key,value such that in combination (memberid, transactionid).

Also, the most important is you  should not keep the update DML statement inside the for loop as it should be a bulk update to avoid hitting governor limits.

So, the key points to consider in your code are,

> 1. Take the SOQL query out of the for loop and find a alternative way as i said above.
> 2. Use collections like maps, set to handle duplicates and avoid vast use of SOQL queries inside for loops.
> 3. Bulkify your DML so that you would not hit governor limits.